# sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc-bin didn't work

Tags: dpkg

Suggested fix didn't work Screen shot attached.  Thanks for the quick response.

```
patwines@patwines-Lenovo-G700:~$  sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc-bin
[sudo] password for patwines: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to reinstall, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/888 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 271725 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../grub-pc-bin_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15) over (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.15+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: install device is not specified.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up shim-signed (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
patwines@patwines-Lenovo-G700:~$
```

Comment: Was the computer already working before something changed or is this a fresh install?

Comment: Have two copies of Ubuntu running on different partitions.  Was using one copy and started having problems.  Problems seemed to start when it didn't remove 2 files after an update.  Switched to the other copy which worked fine.  Did a point upgrade on that copy worked fine for a while and then started having problems.  Problems started after the weekly update and seem to be caused by shim-signed.   Can I do a back-up, erase the lot and reinstall without loosing date?

Comment: When you boot your computer and select the BIOS boot menu, usually F12, do you get a list with multiple Ubuntu entries? If so, do any of them boot properly?

Comment: The bios boot has two entries.  The hard disk and the dvd.  When I select the hard disk it reverts to the normal boot menu.  That menu gives me two Ununtu options, both work with errors.  The first or older one has multiple problems that started with an internal error.  The second ubuntu option, which I am now using mostly works except cannot install new programs.  There is also a window 7 option which works and I try to avoid like the plague.